# What is map_agg equivalent in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to combine two columns to a key-value map. I only did it in presto with `map_agg` but now i have to use snowflake. Anyone knows the function? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It is [object_agg](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_agg.html):

> Returns one OBJECT per group. For each (key, value) input pair, where key must be a VARCHAR and value must be a VARIANT, **the resulting OBJECT contains a key:value field.**